# Scattermapbox in Plotly super laggy with fairly few data points

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I am using Plotly and Mapbox to plot some data points on a map.

In a data frame I have roughly 700 rows, where each row contains a pair of coordinates, i.e. I need to draw a line between each pair. It also have some info about each line so that I can change the color and such for each individual line-pair.

In order to do that I can't just plot everything at once, and I instead need to do 700 plots using `add_trace`. My data frame looks something like:

```
df =

coordinates                              col1    col2           text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[(49.20, 17.51), (49.49, 17.48)]         100     "diamond"      ["dog", "cat"]
[(51.31, 4.26), (51.26, 4.29)]           400     "diamond"      ["milk", "beer"]
[(47.09, 18.04), (47.31, 18.78)]         200     "mocca"        ["cow", "soda"]
...
```

My code for the plotting is something like:

```
fig = go.Figure()
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scattermapbox(
                mode="markers+lines+text",
                lat=list(zip(*row["coordinates"]))[0],
                lon=list(zip(*row["coordinates"]))[1],
                text=row["text"],
                textposition="top center",
                textfont=dict(
                    size=12,
                    color="white",
                ),
                line=dict(
                    width=2 if row["col1"] < 300 else 4,
                    color="red" if row["col2"] == "diamond" else "blue",,
                ),
                marker=dict(
                    size=13 if row["col2"] == "diamond" else 7,
                    symbol="diamond" if row["col2"] == "diamond" else "circle",
                    color="red" if row["col2"] == "diamond" else "blue",
                ),
            )
        )

    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
        mapbox={
            "accesstoken": mapbox_token,
            "center": {"lon": 10, "lat": 50},
            "style": "my_style",
            "zoom": 3,
        },
        showlegend=False,
    )

    fig.show()
```

So as stated, I have roughly 700 in my data frame. And right now, it almost can't be plotted. It takes a lot of time, and I can see it adding a few lines at a time. So basically really laggy, and unusable.

I know it probably has something to do with me using `add_trace` that many times. But still, it seems crazy to me.

I don't know if the solution would be to divide my data frame into red parts, diamond parts etc., and then plot each data from with a full set of coordinates (instead of just pair wise), which would probably reduce the number of `add_traces` from  700 to a few.

But before I do that, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing anything stupid here, or that there may be some kind of other solution ?

The idea is to move it to a React webapp, I don't know if that will change anything ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve your slow execution and heavy response time, a repeated list with Start Latitude (Longitude), End Latitude (Longitude), and None will dramatically improve the speed. However, since it is a single list, only a single line width and color can be set. It is a trade-off between speed and functionality. A small speed improvement can be expected by using df.itertuples().

The [reference](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/#performance-improvement-put-many-lines-in-the-same-trace) also describes an approach to speed improvement.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

latslons = [[(start_lat, start_lon), (end_lat, end_lon)] 
 for start_lat, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon
 in zip(np.random.uniform(24, 49, 700), np.random.uniform(-124, -66, 700), 
        np.random.uniform(24, 49, 700), np.random.uniform(-124, -66, 700))]

df = pd.DataFrame({'coordinates': latslons,
                   'col1': np.random.randint(100,400,700),
                   'col2': np.random.choice(['diamond','mocca'], 700),
                   'text': np.random.choice(['dog','cat','milk','beer','cow','coda'], 700)}
                   )

lats = []
lons = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    lats.append(row.coordinates[0][0])
    lats.append(row.coordinates[1][0])
    lats.append(None)
    lons.append(row.coordinates[0][1])
    lons.append(row.coordinates[1][1])
    lons.append(None)

import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines+text",
        lat=lats,
        lon=lons,
        text=df["text"],
        textposition="top center",
        textfont=dict(
            size=12,
            color="black",
        ),
        line=dict(width=1,color='red'
        ),
        marker=dict(size=5,color='green'
        ),
    )
)

fig.update_layout(
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
    mapbox={
        "accesstoken": mapbox_token,
        "center": {"lon":-95.7129 , "lat": 37.0902},
        "style": "light",
        "zoom": 3,
    },
    showlegend=False,
    height=600,
)

fig.show()
```

[image]